# Polymer Get Paper Input Value

Tags: input, polymer

I am using Polymer for a short time and now i want to get the value of a paper input. I don't know how can I do this.
This is not working:

```
this.form.password
```

I want to get the Value of this field:

```
<paper-input label="Password" type="password" id="password" name="password" size="25" value=""></paper-input>
```

I also want get the Input for submitting of the e-mail input:

```
<paper-input label="Login" id="email" name="email" size="25" value=""></paper-input>
```

For submitting I am using:

```
<paper-button raised value="Login" type="submit" onclick="formhash(this.form, this.form.password);">Login</paper-button>
```

With normal input fields is this working.

Comment: Are you using this form in a polymer element/component ?

Comment: I am using this in a paper-card

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector('#password').value` to get the value of `paper-input` with id `password` in the `formhash()` function call or inside the function definition.

You can also use polymer's [Automatic node finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding) to get value of an element using its `id`. In which keep the form/input in custom-element and use `this.$.password.value` to get the value of an element with id `password`. Like this

```
<!-- create a custom component my-form --> 
<dom-module id="my-form">
    <template> 
      <form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post">
        <paper-input name="name" label="name" id="name"></paper-input>
        <paper-button raised on-click="submitForm">Submit</paper-button>
      </form>
    </template>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Polymer({
            is: "my-form",
            submitForm: function() {
                alert(this.$.name.value);
                if(this.$.name.value != "") // whatever input check
                   this.$.form.submit();
            }
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>

<my-form></my-form> <!-- use custom-component my-form -->
```

Comment: Now I can get the Value, but I can not submit the form. this.$.submit(); is not working or this.submit(); or something else. How can I submit now.

Comment: use `this.$.form.submit()` where `form` is the **id** of `form` tag

Comment: Here is a working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ruhiqotupi/edit?html,console,output), check the console log after clicking the submit button, the post/get request is blocked by jsbin due to CORS. `submit()` call creating a request. btw Your question was about accessing the input-value, and it is working.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `<form>` you can also simply store the paper-input values in instance variables and use them later wherever you want.

All you have to do is store the input inside a value like this:

`<paper-input label="Password" type="password" id="password" name="password" size="25" value="{{valueNameToStore}}"></paper-input>`

And later access it like this:

`var myPassword = this.valueNameToStore;`

Answer (score 0):

Using `<form is="iron-form">` allows you to use `<paper-input>` and other input elements in forms https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form

```
<form is="iron-form" id="form" method="post" action="/form/handler">
  <paper-input name="name" label="name"></paper-input>
  <input name="address">
  ...
  <paper-button raised onclick="submitForm()">Submit</paper-button>
</form>


function submitForm() {
  document.getElementById('form').submit();
}
```

Comment: But this don't work. I need the value for the formhash. How can i get the value and form it.

Answer (score 0):

or, sometimes you can try `this.$.password.value` to get the value for password.