# How to get get the value from a paper input element in JavaScript using document.getElementById('elementID')

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am unable to retrieve the value of a paper input in polymer js. I am using paper input and when i try to fetch the value using document.getElementById('ID') it does not works and says Cannot read property 'value' of null.

```
<paper-input id='firstName' label="First name" auto-validate allowed-pattern="([a-zA-Z])" required error-message="Field is required">
</paper-input>
<paper-button id="submitButton" raised type="submit" on-click="validateForm">Submit</paper-button>
```

JS

```
validateForm() {
    alert (document.getElementById('firstName').value );
}
```

Comment: Your paper element probably doesn't exist in the scope of `validateForm()`. You may need to ensure that it runs inside of an `onload`, or chain it as a callback of the generation of the paper elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bad practise to make use of the getElementById() when working with Polymer. Rather then that I would make use of [Automatic node finding in Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom)
I added an example below. I also changed your on-click to a on-tap as Polymer recommends this.
A other way would be to get the value with a querySelector().value
as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513851/polymer-get-paper-input-value). However, I prefer the data-binding way to do so.

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">
  <template>
    <paper-input id='firstName' label="First name" value="[[inputValue]]"
                 auto-validate allowed-pattern="([a-zA-Z])" required error-message="Field is required">
   </paper-input>
   <paper-button id="submitButton" raised
                 on-tap="validateForm">Submit</paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'x-custom',
        properties: {
          inputValue: {
            type: String
        }
      },

      validateForm: function() {
        console.log(this.inputValue);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: It is recommended use properties and data binding for the communication between components. Furthermore, unidirectional is encouraged. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAW4YDLtPVs#t=1m40s

Comment: So my answer is correct. Just added the additional link to show the other options or possible duplicates. @FrankR. thanks for spotting and correcting that '$' mistake.